# How to send a license expiration notice using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, triggers, alert

In my current project, I have a table full of drivers' information with a column containing the expiration dates of their drivers' licenses.

I want to send an alert email when their license expires in the next 20 days. I want this check to happen on a daily basis.

If I bind this to an action such as a user's login, I'm afraid it may be missed in certain cases (like a weekend when no one logs in) etc.

Is there a way to do this check routinely without any user intervention? I'm using CodeIgniter as my PHP framework. My project's running on a shared hosting account with PHP 5.3 and MySql 5.

Comment: Why don't you just run a simple script that select everything from the DB where the date is within 20 days? Then send emails to those people. You could set it up to be run at a certain time, or even just run it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a controller which triggers the checks/emails etc in some way shape or form, then simply [run CI via the command line](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html) in a Cronjob which runs per minute/hour/day etc

```
$ cd /path/to/project && php index.php tools message
```

As you're on shared hosting, you probably don't have access to Crontab, there are various services such as http://www.mywebcron.com/ which you can set up Cronjobs on. Obviously in this case the above is only part valid- rather than use php in the command line, you'd need to use wget (or similar) to access the controller via HTTP.